# Sending multiple items to Node JS to do a bulk delete

Tags: node.js

To avoid making multiple http calls from an Angular app, if I want to make one call and send multiple id strings to a node js back-end for deletion, should I be sending them as JSON?

If anyone can point me to a good example that would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just send the ID's in a JSON Format as shown below

```
id:"1000,1001,1002"
```

and in NodeJS if you are using MYSQL the following query works for delete

```
let ids = req.body.id;//To get the id sent in JSON Format

delete from table_name where id in (ids)
```

**Comment below if u need any further guidance**

Answer (score 2):

You also try with pass the array of ids in the request.

**Example :**

```
var idArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    $http(
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: '/items',
      params: {
        id: JSON.stringify(idArray) 
      }
    )
```

Comment: Both answers have given me what I need but right now I call the default delete on the table, which expects one string as a parameter, I assume I have to create a function to handle the incoming array?